# UPDATE базы postrgresql

Tags: python, postgresql

```
INSERT INTO main_parse_user ("user_id","group_id", "username", "bio", "first_name") 
VALUES ($1,$2,$3,$4,$5) 
ON CONFLICT (user_id) 
DO UPDATE 
SET ("group_id", "username", "bio", "first_name") = (EXCLUDED.group_id, EXCLUDED.username, EXCLUDED.bio,EXCLUDED.first_name)
```

Вот мой код для добавления и одновременно редактирования данных в бд

Сейчас оно работает таким образом:

`user_id|group_id|@username|bio|first_name`

И если в базе имелся ранее `user_id` то он редактирует и добавляет в остальные поля данные из нового запроса

Но мне нужно сделать чуть иначе

Допустим у меня в базе есть данные

`12345|-10015488|@abcd|None|Dev`

И я добавил новую сточку с точно таким же ID но с изменением в `bio`

`12345|-10015488|@abcd|Developer|Dev`

И вот когда у меня на старой бд не указан `bio` мне надо добавлять новое значение в бд, а если изначально в `bio` была информация то алгоритм просто пропускает

Comment: ```.. SET column = COALESCE(EXCLUDED.column, INSERTED.column) ..```. Если в поле есть значение - COALESCE вернёт его, и оно останется неизменным. Если в поле нет значения (NULL) - COALESCE вернёт вставляемое значение. И лучше для каждого поля выражение присвоения писать отдельно, не пользуясь row constructor.

Comment: @Akina Могу ли я вас попросить помочь с интеграцией этого кода, я не совсем понял куда и как его ставить )